# How to customize Cloudera Hue UI

Tags: python, mako, hue, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to customize the Cloudera Hue user interface by, for example, changing the "About Hue" page to contain more content. I'm new to Hue and I'm not sure of the proper way to do this.

I've tried editing the mako files (e.g. removing "Configuration" and "Server Logs" list items from about_layout.mako). However, when I restart Hue in the cloudera manager and refresh the About Hue page, I do not see the changes reflected. This may not be the correct way to customize Hue at all, I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This mean that you are not modifying the real files. If you modify just templates you don't need to restart you. If you are looking at customizing it, it is recommended to use the dev version https://github.com/cloudera/hue#getting-started and look at some dev posts: http://gethue.com/category/programming/

Comment: You're right, I was not modifying the correct file. Now that I'm modifying the correct file I don't need to restart Hue. Thanks for your advice!